# Mootools inject after not working

Tags: javascript, mootools, inject

Mootools code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var homeLink = $$('a.pathway');
    new Element('a', {'href': '/ru/produktsiya', 'html': 'Click me!'}).inject(homeLink, 'after');

});
```

Why didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$$` returns a collection of elements, which you cannot inject a single element after, of course.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  var homeLink = $$('a.pathway');
  new Element('a[href="/ru/produktsiya"][text="Click me!"]'}).inject(homeLink[0], 'after');
});
```

You can also use CSS selector logic to more easily create elements, as I've done above: